# Not able to update RecurrenceTimeZoneSidKey field on task object

Tags: tasks, sobject, fls

What are the work around the task object in Salesforce, i am trying to update task which is having information in the form of JavaScript object which is mentioned below

and when i am trying to update this field using **Developer Console** I got this error 
**INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, The field RecurrenceTimeZoneSidKey is invalid.: [RecurrenceTimeZoneSidKey]**

> [![We can not able to update fields throws error which is 
>   **{errors:{fields:'RecurrenceTimeZoneSidKey', message:'Recurrence Time Zone: bad value for restricted picklist field: (GMT+13:00) Phoenix Is. Time (Pacific/Enderbury)', statusCode:'INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST', }, id:null, success:'false', }**
>   ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRxCk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRxCk.png)[image]

i am not able to find the field **RecurrenceTimeZoneSidKey** in task object. i searched this field in **Activity, Task, Event** and when i trying to give **field level security** of these, we are not getting this **RecurrenceTimeZoneSidKey** field in task object setting of **system administrator** profile but these fields are present in workbench but i can't able to put this field on **Task or event layout**

please provide me logic and solution of this topic thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you're using the wrong value. The values allowed are exactly as follows:

- Pacific/Kiritimati
- Pacific/Enderbury
- Pacific/Tongatapu
- Pacific/Chatham
- Asia/Kamchatka
- Pacific/Auckland
- Pacific/Fiji
- Pacific/Guadalcanal
- Pacific/Norfolk
- Australia/Lord_Howe
- Australia/Brisbane
- Australia/Sydney
- Australia/Adelaide
- Australia/Darwin
- Asia/Seoul
- Asia/Tokyo
- Asia/Hong_Kong
- Asia/Kuala_Lumpur
- Asia/Manila
- Asia/Shanghai
- Asia/Singapore
- Asia/Taipei
- Australia/Perth
- Asia/Bangkok
- Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh
- Asia/Jakarta
- Asia/Rangoon
- Asia/Dhaka
- Asia/Kathmandu
- Asia/Colombo
- Asia/Kolkata
- Asia/Karachi
- Asia/Tashkent
- Asia/Yekaterinburg
- Asia/Kabul
- Asia/Tehran
- Asia/Baku
- Asia/Dubai
- Asia/Tbilisi
- Asia/Yerevan
- Africa/Nairobi
- Asia/Baghdad
- Asia/Beirut
- Asia/Jerusalem
- Asia/Kuwait
- Asia/Riyadh
- Europe/Athens
- Europe/Bucharest
- Europe/Helsinki
- Europe/Istanbul
- Europe/Minsk
- Europe/Moscow
- Africa/Cairo
- Africa/Johannesburg
- Europe/Amsterdam
- Europe/Berlin
- Europe/Brussels
- Europe/Paris
- Europe/Prague
- Europe/Rome
- Africa/Algiers
- Africa/Casablanca
- Europe/Dublin
- Europe/Lisbon
- Europe/London
- America/Scoresbysund
- Atlantic/Azores
- GMT
- Atlantic/Cape_Verde
- Atlantic/South_Georgia
- America/St_Johns
- America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires
- America/Halifax
- America/Santiago
- America/Sao_Paulo
- Atlantic/Bermuda
- America/Caracas
- America/Indiana/Indianapolis
- America/New_York
- America/Puerto_Rico
- America/Bogota
- America/Chicago
- America/Lima
- America/Mexico_City
- America/Panama
- America/Denver
- America/El_Salvador
- America/Mazatlan
- America/Los_Angeles
- America/Phoenix
- America/Tijuana
- America/Anchorage
- Pacific/Pitcairn
- America/Adak
- Pacific/Gambier
- Pacific/Marquesas
- Pacific/Honolulu
- Pacific/Niue
- Pacific/Pago_Pago

Note that these values are different than their labels:

- (GMT+14:00) Line Is. Time (Pacific/Kiritimati)
- (GMT+13:00) Phoenix Is. Time (Pacific/Enderbury)
- (GMT+13:00) Tonga Time (Pacific/Tongatapu)
- (GMT+12:45) Chatham Standard Time (Pacific/Chatham)
- (GMT+12:00) Petropavlovsk-Kamchatski Time (Asia/Kamchatka)
- (GMT+12:00) New Zealand Standard Time (Pacific/Auckland)
- (GMT+12:00) Fiji Time (Pacific/Fiji)
- (GMT+11:00) Solomon Is. Time (Pacific/Guadalcanal)
- (GMT+11:00) Norfolk Time (Pacific/Norfolk)
- (GMT+10:30) Lord Howe Standard Time (Australia/Lord_Howe)
- (GMT+10:00) Australian Eastern Standard Time (Queensland) (Australia/Brisbane)
- (GMT+10:00) Australian Eastern Standard Time (New South Wales) (Australia/Sydney)
- (GMT+09:30) Australian Central Standard Time (South Australia) (Australia/Adelaide)
- (GMT+09:30) Australian Central Standard Time (Northern Territory) (Australia/Darwin)
- (GMT+09:00) Korea Standard Time (Asia/Seoul)
- (GMT+09:00) Japan Standard Time (Asia/Tokyo)
- (GMT+08:00) Hong Kong Time (Asia/Hong_Kong)
- (GMT+08:00) Malaysia Time (Asia/Kuala_Lumpur)
- (GMT+08:00) Philippines Time (Asia/Manila)
- (GMT+08:00) China Standard Time (Asia/Shanghai)
- (GMT+08:00) Singapore Time (Asia/Singapore)
- (GMT+08:00) China Standard Time (Asia/Taipei)
- (GMT+08:00) Australian Western Standard Time (Australia/Perth)
- (GMT+07:00) Indochina Time (Asia/Bangkok)
- (GMT+07:00) Indochina Time (Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh)
- (GMT+07:00) West Indonesia Time (Asia/Jakarta)
- (GMT+06:30) Myanmar Time (Asia/Rangoon)
- (GMT+06:00) Bangladesh Time (Asia/Dhaka)
- (GMT+05:45) Nepal Time (Asia/Kathmandu)
- (GMT+05:30) India Standard Time (Asia/Colombo)
- (GMT+05:30) India Standard Time (Asia/Kolkata)
- (GMT+05:00) Pakistan Time (Asia/Karachi)
- (GMT+05:00) Uzbekistan Time (Asia/Tashkent)
- (GMT+05:00) Yekaterinburg Time (Asia/Yekaterinburg)
- (GMT+04:30) Afghanistan Time (Asia/Kabul)
- (GMT+04:30) Iran Daylight Time (Asia/Tehran)
- (GMT+04:00) Azerbaijan Time (Asia/Baku)
- (GMT+04:00) Gulf Standard Time (Asia/Dubai)
- (GMT+04:00) Georgia Time (Asia/Tbilisi)
- (GMT+04:00) Armenia Time (Asia/Yerevan)
- (GMT+03:00) Eastern African Time (Africa/Nairobi)
- (GMT+03:00) Arabia Standard Time (Asia/Baghdad)
- (GMT+03:00) Eastern European Summer Time (Asia/Beirut)
- (GMT+03:00) Israel Daylight Time (Asia/Jerusalem)
- (GMT+03:00) Arabia Standard Time (Asia/Kuwait)
- (GMT+03:00) Arabia Standard Time (Asia/Riyadh)
- (GMT+03:00) Eastern European Summer Time (Europe/Athens)
- (GMT+03:00) Eastern European Summer Time (Europe/Bucharest)
- (GMT+03:00) Eastern European Summer Time (Europe/Helsinki)
- (GMT+03:00) Eastern European Time (Europe/Istanbul)
- (GMT+03:00) Moscow Standard Time (Europe/Minsk)
- (GMT+03:00) Moscow Standard Time (Europe/Moscow)
- (GMT+02:00) Eastern European Time (Africa/Cairo)
- (GMT+02:00) South Africa Standard Time (Africa/Johannesburg)
- (GMT+02:00) Central European Summer Time (Europe/Amsterdam)
- (GMT+02:00) Central European Summer Time (Europe/Berlin)
- (GMT+02:00) Central European Summer Time (Europe/Brussels)
- (GMT+02:00) Central European Summer Time (Europe/Paris)
- (GMT+02:00) Central European Summer Time (Europe/Prague)
- (GMT+02:00) Central European Summer Time (Europe/Rome)
- (GMT+01:00) Central European Time (Africa/Algiers)
- (GMT+01:00) Western European Summer Time (Africa/Casablanca)
- (GMT+01:00) Irish Summer Time (Europe/Dublin)
- (GMT+01:00) Western European Summer Time (Europe/Lisbon)
- (GMT+01:00) British Summer Time (Europe/London)
- (GMT+00:00) Eastern Greenland Summer Time (America/Scoresbysund)
- (GMT+00:00) Azores Summer Time (Atlantic/Azores)
- (GMT+00:00) Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)
- (GMT-01:00) Cape Verde Time (Atlantic/Cape_Verde)
- (GMT-02:00) South Georgia Standard Time (Atlantic/South_Georgia)
- (GMT-02:30) Newfoundland Daylight Time (America/St_Johns)
- (GMT-03:00) Argentine Time (America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires)
- (GMT-03:00) Atlantic Daylight Time (America/Halifax)
- (GMT-03:00) Chile Summer Time (America/Santiago)
- (GMT-03:00) Brasilia Time (America/Sao_Paulo)
- (GMT-03:00) Atlantic Daylight Time (Atlantic/Bermuda)
- (GMT-04:00) Venezuela Time (America/Caracas)
- (GMT-04:00) Eastern Daylight Time (America/Indiana/Indianapolis)
- (GMT-04:00) Eastern Daylight Time (America/New_York)
- (GMT-04:00) Atlantic Standard Time (America/Puerto_Rico)
- (GMT-05:00) Colombia Time (America/Bogota)
- (GMT-05:00) Central Daylight Time (America/Chicago)
- (GMT-05:00) Peru Time (America/Lima)
- (GMT-05:00) Central Daylight Time (America/Mexico_City)
- (GMT-05:00) Eastern Standard Time (America/Panama)
- (GMT-06:00) Mountain Daylight Time (America/Denver)
- (GMT-06:00) Central Standard Time (America/El_Salvador)
- (GMT-06:00) Mountain Daylight Time (America/Mazatlan)
- (GMT-07:00) Pacific Daylight Time (America/Los_Angeles)
- (GMT-07:00) Mountain Standard Time (America/Phoenix)
- (GMT-07:00) Pacific Daylight Time (America/Tijuana)
- (GMT-08:00) Alaska Daylight Time (America/Anchorage)
- (GMT-08:00) Pitcairn Standard Time (Pacific/Pitcairn)
- (GMT-09:00) Hawaii-Aleutian Daylight Time (America/Adak)
- (GMT-09:00) Gambier Time (Pacific/Gambier)
- (GMT-09:30) Marquesas Time (Pacific/Marquesas)
- (GMT-10:00) Hawaii-Aleutian Standard Time (Pacific/Honolulu)
- (GMT-11:00) Niue Time (Pacific/Niue)
- (GMT-11:00) Samoa Standard Time (Pacific/Pago_Pago)

Whenever you're in doubt, always check the values in the WSDL, or by using a describe call, like this code:

```
String[] values = new String[0];
SObjectField field = Task.RecurrenceTimeZoneSidKey;
for(PicklistEntry value: field.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()) {
    values.add('Value: "'+value.getValue()+'", Label: "' + value.getLabel()+'"');
}
System.debug(String.join(values,'\n'));
```

You can use this code to get a list of values and their corresponding labels using Apex Code.